# How to register a headset button event in react native?

Tags: react-native

I'm using the latest version of React Native. I'm trying to console log something whenever the headset button is clicked on Android. So far, I've been unsuccessful.

I tried the `react-native-music-control`. In the docs it says that

```
MusicControl.on('togglePlayPause', ()=>{console.log('clicked')})
```

should work. But I'm not sure if its only for ios or android too.

This is my componentDidMount (the render returns a 'hello' text).

```
 componentDidMount() {
    MusicControl.enableControl('play', true);
    MusicControl.enableControl('pause', true);
    MusicControl.enableControl('stop', true);
    MusicControl.enableControl('togglePlayPause', true);
    MusicControl.on('play', () => { console.log('----'); });
    MusicControl.on('pause', () => { console.log('----'); });
    MusicControl.on('togglePlayPause', () => { console.log('----'); });
  }
```

'----' is logged only when I disconnect the headset and not any other time.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

So, the package react-native-keyevent works really well with android. After linking the package, I had to configure it in the MainActivity.java (which I was skipping by mistake).
After I did that, it worked properly in Android.

Answer (score 1):

The official doc on [github](https://github.com/tanguyantoine/react-native-music-control) says:

```
MusicControl.on('togglePlayPause', ()=> {}); // iOS only
```

The `iOS only` comment states pretty clearly that this event is only available on iOS and would not trigger on Android

Comment: I had found this in the issues. https://github.com/tanguyantoine/react-native-music-control/issues/123#issuecomment-355481720